# Visual Studio macro: Find files that aren't included in the project?

Tags: visual-studio, macros, visual-studio-macros

I'd like to write a macro to crawl through the files in my project directory and find files that aren't included in the project.

In playing around with the DTE object, I see that the `Project` object has `ProjectItems`; if a `ProjectItem` represents a directory, then it has its own `ProjectItems` collection. This gives me all files that are included in the project.

So I could crawl recursively through each ProjectItems collection, and for each ProjectItem that's a directory, check to see if there are files in the file system that don't have a corresponding ProjectItem. This seems clumsy, though.

Any ideas of a simpler way to approach this?

Comment: Get a list of all directories involved, find every file in them, save their full paths into a set data structure. Now go through all files in your project and remove them from the set (pre-pend the right path). Then examine what you have left over ...

Comment: Thanks - why not just post this as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @JaredPar and @lpthnc for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up using an approach very similar to what @JaredPar outlines above. Here's my working macro FWIW.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports EnvDTE

Public Module Main

    Sub IncludeNewFiles()
        Dim Count As Integer = 0
        For Each Project As Project In DTE.Solution.Projects
            If Project.UniqueName.EndsWith(".vbproj") Then
                Dim NewFiles As List(Of String) = GetFilesNotInProject(Project)
                For Each File In NewFiles
                    Project.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(File)
                Next
                Count += NewFiles.Count
            End If
        Next
        DTE.StatusBar.Text = String.Format("{0} new file{1} included in the project.", Count, If(Count = 1, "", "s"))
    End Sub

    Private Function GetAllProjectFiles(ByVal ProjectItems As ProjectItems, ByVal Extension As String) As List(Of String)
        GetAllProjectFiles = New List(Of String)
        For Each ProjectItem As ProjectItem In ProjectItems
            For i As Integer = 1 To ProjectItem.FileCount
                Dim FileName As String = ProjectItem.FileNames(i)
                If Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower = Extension Then
                    GetAllProjectFiles.Add(fileName)
                End If
            Next
            GetAllProjectFiles.AddRange(GetAllProjectFiles(ProjectItem.ProjectItems, Extension))
        Next
    End Function

    Private Function GetFilesNotInProject(ByVal Project As Project) As List(Of String)
        Dim StartPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Project.FullName)
        Dim ProjectFiles As List(Of String) = GetAllProjectFiles(Project.ProjectItems, ".vb")
        GetFilesNotInProject = New List(Of String)
        For Each file In Directory.GetFiles(StartPath, "*.vb", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            If Not ProjectFiles.Contains(file) Then GetFilesNotInProject.Add(file)
        Next
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Will this work for the entire solution. I have loads of excluded files which I want to delete.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta - you'd probably have to walk through the solution's projects one by one, and do this for each one.

Comment: Seems that [Macros are no longer available in Visual Studio 2012](http://www.dzone.com/articles/missing-macros-visual-studio). Any possible solution for VS 2012?

Answer (score 11):

Here is the C# version of your code:

```
public static void IncludeNewFiles()
{
    int count = 0;
    EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2;
    List<string> newfiles;

    dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");

    foreach (Project project in dte2.Solution.Projects)
    {
        if (project.UniqueName.EndsWith(".csproj"))
        {
            newfiles = GetFilesNotInProject(project);

            foreach (var file in newfiles)
                project.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(file);

            count += newfiles.Count;
        }
    }
    dte2.StatusBar.Text = String.Format("{0} new file{1} included in the project.", count, (count == 1 ? "" : "s"));
}

public static List<string> GetAllProjectFiles(ProjectItems projectItems, string extension)
{
    List<string> returnValue = new List<string>();

    foreach(ProjectItem projectItem in projectItems)
    {
        for (short i = 1; i <= projectItems.Count; i++)
        {
            string fileName = projectItem.FileNames[i];
            if (Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower() == extension)
                returnValue.Add(fileName);
        }
        returnValue.AddRange(GetAllProjectFiles(projectItem.ProjectItems, extension));        
    }

    return returnValue;
}

public static List<string> GetFilesNotInProject(Project project)
{
    List<string> returnValue = new List<string>();
    string startPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(project.FullName);
    List<string> projectFiles = GetAllProjectFiles(project.ProjectItems, ".cs");

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(startPath, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        if (!projectFiles.Contains(file)) returnValue.Add(file);

    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach I would take is to

1. Enumerate the file system looking for all files
2. Check and see if the given file has an associated project item.

Here is a quick bit of sample code

```
Function ContainsItem(p as Project, fileName as String) As Boolean
  Try
    Return p.ProjectItems.Item(fileName)
  Catch ex As ArgumentException
    Return False
  End Try
End Function

Function CotainsItem(dte as DTE, fileName as String) As Boolean
  For Each p As Project in dte.Solution.Projects
    Return ContainsItem(p, fileName)
  Next
End Function

Function GetFilesNotInProject(dte as DTE, startPath as String) as List(Of String)
  Dim list As New List(Of String)
  Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(startPath, "*.cs", SearchOPtions.AllDirectories)
  For Each file in files 
    If Not ContainsItem(dte, file) Then
      list.Add(file)
    End If
  Next
  Return list
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks - this helped a lot. It doesn't quite work as is, because `p.ProjectItems` only contains items at the root of the project; you have to recurse through each ProjectItem's own ProjectItems collection in turn. In the code I've posted, I build a list of existing files and then use that to see what's not included.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with PowerShell. The PowerShell script in my other post will do this for you. The script will get the list of included files from the project file and compare that against the files on disk. You will get the set of files that are on disk but not included in the project. You can either delete them or pend them as deletes for TFS.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23420956/846428